# Access XAML object from code

Tags: wpf, xaml

I created a UserControl in WPF:

In Xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="OutlookPanel.MailRelation"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="300" Width="300"
    xmlns:graph="clr-namespace:MyPanel"
>
 <DockPanel>
<graph:Graph Name="theGraph" NodesBindingPath="ChildNodes"
               NodeTemplateSelector="{StaticResource nodeTemplateSelector}">
..
 </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

I cs:

```
object theThing = e.Parameter;
                    ((MailRelation)sender).theGraph.CenterObject = theThing;
```

This last sentence does not work as theGraph is not accessible.
Any idea why i can access theGraph ?

Thanks

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name="theGraph"

should be

x:Name="theGraph"

from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752059.aspx

> x:Name: Specifies a run-time object
>   name for the instance that exists in
>   run-time code after an object element
>   is processed. You use x:Name for cases
>   of naming elements where the
>   equivalent WPF framework-level Name
>   property is not supported. This
>   happens in certain animation
>   scenarios.

Comment: Wow, it is true... Can you explain the difference?

Comment: Depends on what Graph is. What class does it extend?

Comment: if the object you are working with does not contain a Name field already then you can use x:Name, which i believe is an extended property.

Answer (score -2):

Probably because that property is private.  Provide a public getter and you should be able to get it.  In your code, add something like

```
 public Graph TheGraph  { get { return theGraph; } }
```

Comment: Hi,
No it does not work :
public partial class MailRelation : UserControl
    {
        public Graph TheGraph  { get { return theGraph; } }
        
        static MailRelation()
        {}

the Graph is also not seen...
John

Comment: Usually, that has been my problem.  Did you change the other line of code to use TheGraph instead of theGraph?